# Dataset to JSON using C#/VB.Net

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, dataset

I have a dataset with the following data:
[image]

I want to convert this data into JSON in the following format:

```
{
    "Resource": [
        {
            "resourceID": "1",
            "resourceName": "Jonathan",
            "Customer": [
                {
                    "customerID": "1",
                    "firstName": "Alec",
                    "lastName": "Stewart",
                    "Appointments": [
                        {
                            "appointmentID": "1",
                            "startDate": "01-01-2015",
                            "endDate": "01-01-2015"
                        },
                        {
                            "appointmentID": "2",
                            "startDate": "01-01-2015",
                            "endDate":"01-01-2015",
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "customerID": "2",
                    "firstName": "Chris",
                    "lastName": "Douglas",
                    "Appointments": [
                        {
                            "appointmentID": "3",
                            "startDate": "01-01-2015",
                            "endDate": "01-01-2015",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "resourceID": "2",
            "resourceName": "Matthew",
            "Customer": [
                {
                    "customerID": "3",
                    "firstName": "Shirley",
                    "lastName": "Graham",
                    "Appointments": [
                        {
                            "appointmentID": "4",
                            "startDate": "01-01-2015",
                            "endDate": "01-01-2015",
                        },
                        {
                            "appointmentID": "5",
                            "startDate": "01-01-2015",
                            "endDate": "01-01-2015"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "customerID": "4",
                    "firstName": "Ricardo",
                    "lastName": "Powell",
                    "Appointments": [
                        {
                            "appointmentID": "6",
                            "startDate": "01-01-2015",
                            "endDate": "01-01-2015"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any faster way that I can use in VB.Net to convert it directly to JSON? Should I go with creating classes and list and iterate the dataset to create object of nested classes and then serialize it or it can be achieved in a different way? Can someone tell me about the way to serialize the dataset to JSON? I am okay with C# as well.

Comment: first convert this Dataset in entity list as per your requirement then serialize it.

Comment: My problem is not "how to serialize dataset to JSON". My question specifies "Dataset to JSON using VB.Net". that means I need to write a code that takes rows from dataset and assign three different classes their properties and then serialize it. I am unable to iterate for nested objects.

Comment: Use LINQ or foreach to traverse all the rows and column and prepare an entity list which needs to be serialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have nested class like below:

```
[Serializable]
public class Resource
{
    public string resourceID { get; set; }
    public string resourceName { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string customerID { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public string appointmentID { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    public string endDate { get; set; }
}
```

After you populate the data in your class, you can use JavaScriptSerializer class which is already part of System.Web.Script.Serialization like below:

```
var resources = new List<Resource>();
//populate resources data here

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
var resourceJSON = serializer.Serialize(resources); //result
```

//You can populate resources class using code below:

```
// Fill the DataSet
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("tblResources");
adapter.Fill(dataSet);

//Populate nested class base on DataSet
var resources = new List<Resource>();

string currentResourceID = string.Empty;
string currentCustomerID = string.Empty;
int totalRows = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

var resource = new Resource();
var customer = new Customer();
var customers = new List<Customer>();
var appointments = new List<Appointment>();
bool newResource = false;
bool newCustomer = false;

for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
{
    var resourceID = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["resourceID"].ToString();
    var resourceName = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["resourceName"].ToString();
    var customerID = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["customerID"].ToString();
    var firstName = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["firstName"].ToString();
    var lastName = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["lastName"].ToString();
    var appointmentID = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["appointmentID"].ToString();
    var startDate = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["startDate"].ToString();
    var endDate = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["endDate"].ToString();

    if (!currentResourceID.Equals(resourceID))
    {
        currentResourceID = resourceID;

        resource = new Resource()
        {
            resourceID = resourceID,
            resourceName = resourceName
        };

        resources.Add(resource);

        newResource = true;
    }
    else
    {
        newResource = false;
    }

    if (newResource)
    {
        customers = new List<Customer>();

        resource.Customers = customers;
        currentCustomerID = string.Empty;

    }

    if (!currentCustomerID.Equals(customerID))
    {
        currentCustomerID = customerID;

        customer = new Customer()
        {
            customerID = customerID,
            firstName = firstName,
            lastName = lastName
        };


        customers.Add(customer);

        newCustomer = true;
    }
    else
    {
        newCustomer = false;
    }

    if (newCustomer)
    {
        appointments = new List<Appointment>();

        customer.Appointments = appointments;

    }

    var appointment = new Appointment()
    {
        appointmentID = appointmentID,
        startDate = startDate,
        endDate = endDate
    };

    appointments.Add(appointment);

}

//Convert nested class to json
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
var resourceJSON = serializer.Serialize(resources);
```

Comment: Thanks. I already have class structure defined. The real challenge for me is to iterate the dataset and assign the classes their properties from it and then serialize the object.I just can't get the iteration working.

Comment: Edited code to add the populate of resources class from dataset.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, [newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is a real beauty. You could do this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourdataset, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: My issue is not about how to serialize. I know newtonsoft can serialize object for me. My issue here is to convert the linear data into nested objects. Sorry if I did not explain it well in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use for .NET <> JSON Newtonsofts JSON at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json. It does everything and more what you need!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned u can use NewtonSoft for this. But there is no default behavior for this. To create a more generic solution u can write a Custom JsonConverter for the Newtonsoft. And implement a clean way for your project to serialize or deserialize.

See a example at: http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/ or http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm.